# Alter url aliases programmatically

Tags: 8, path-aliases

I have a pattern set up to create the URL aliases based on a field of type list text.

the field looks like this:

selection 1|selection 1

selection 2|selection 2

How can I alter the alias so it will show something like this:

www.example.com/1-was-selected rather than www.example.com/selection-1

UPDATE:
I'm using Pathauto for the patterns.

Comment: Not completely clear what you are asking ... are you using pathauto for the patterns ? if its your own custom module please post some code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.I'm using pathauto for the patterns.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a custom token and use that in my alias. I'm assuming you're using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) to create your aliases. [This page](https://github.com/pareshaU/Drupal8/blob/master/Create%20custom%20token%20and%20add%20values%20to%20token.) gives a pretty good example of how to create your own token. Then you can select your token in the pathauto UI.

You can create the [hook_tokens_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.5.x) hook basically exactly as they've done, but replacing the "customs" with your real values. For your [hook_tokens](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.5.x) implementation, you should have access to the entity in the `$data` variable i.e., `$data['node']` will have your node object if you're using this for nodes. From there you should be able to do something like `$data['node']->field_your_list_field->getValue()` to get the value of your field. Just be sure to return a `$replacements` array where the key is your custom_token and the value is the value to replace with, in your case this would be something like `you-selected-value-X`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I guess you should create a token in a custome module.
Todo so you should implement [hook_token_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_token_info/8.2.x) and then [hook_tokens()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens/8.2.x).

Or maybe you could look at [hook_tokens_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21token.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/8.5.x) and target the token you are actually using in your pattern to changed its rendering.

example from durpal.org:

```
function hook_tokens_alter(array &$replacements, array $context, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $options = $context['options'];

  if (isset($options['langcode'])) {
    $url_options['language'] = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage($options['langcode']);
    $langcode = $options['langcode'];
  }
  else {
    $langcode = NULL;
  }

  if ($context['type'] == 'node' && !empty($context['data']['node'])) {
    $node = $context['data']['node'];

    // Alter the [node:title] token, and replace it with the rendered content
    // of a field (field_title).
    if (isset($context['tokens']['title'])) {
      $title = $node->field_title->view('default');
      $replacements[$context['tokens']['title']] = drupal_render($title);
    }
  }
}
```